# google app script export csv with semicolon instead of comma

Tags: google-apps-script, automatic-semicolon-insertion

I am using the code below to export a google spreadsheet to CSV in a specific folder.
I need to have a semicolon (;) as delimiter instead of a comma (,)

```
function saveAsCSV() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var ssname = ss.getName();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("MyID");
var folder = parentFolder;
var curDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "yyyyMMdd")

var fileName = "MyName" + curDate + ".csv";
var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + ss.getId() + "/export? 
exportFormat=csv&format=csv";  
var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();  
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + sheet.getSheetId(), {
headers: {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token
}
});
folder.createFile(response.getBlob().setName(fileName));
}
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to replace `,` to `;` for the retrieved CSV data.
- You want to create the replaced data as a file.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer?

### Modification points:

- The data that `;` is used as the delimiter instead of `,` is no mimeType of `text/csv`. In this case, it is required to be `text/plain`.
- In your script, I would like to propose the following 2 patterns.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the values are retrieved and the data separated by `;` is created.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified please modify as follows.

##### From:

```
var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + ss.getId() + "/export? 
exportFormat=csv&format=csv";  
var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();  
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + sheet.getSheetId(), {
headers: {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token
}
});
folder.createFile(response.getBlob().setName(fileName));
```

##### To:

```
var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
var outputData = values.map(r => r.join(";")).join("\n");
folder.createFile(fileName, outputData, MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT);
```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, the retrieved CSV data is converted.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified please modify as follows.

##### From:

```
folder.createFile(response.getBlob().setName(fileName));
```

##### To:

```
var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(response.getBlob().getDataAsString());
var outputData = csvData.map(r => r.join(";")).join("\n");
folder.createFile(fileName, outputData, MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT);
```

### Note:

- Please enable V8.

### Reference:

- [createFile(name, content, mimeType)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#createfilename,-content,-mimetype)